# Find the joint density function of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ where $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ and $Y_2=\frac{X_2}{X_1+X_2}$, and the joint density function

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, density-function

Let the joint density function of $(X_1, X_2)$ is given by
\begin{align*}
f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) =
\begin{cases}
x_1e^{-x_1-x_2}, & x_1,x_2 > 0 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
\end{align*}

Is it true that the formula of joint density function of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ given as follows:
$$f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2) = f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) |J(x_1,x_2)|^{-1},$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian matrix?
If yes, I got the answer, but I didn't know why the double integral over $(0,\infty)$ was diverges?

Any helps? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Did you remember that $0<Y_2<1$? You probably integtated from $0$ to $\infty$ w.r.t the  second variable

Answer (score 1):

Here $x_1=y_1(1-y_2)$ and $x_2=y_1y_2$ so the Jacobian is
$$\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial x_1}{\partial y_2}\\
\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_1} & \frac{\partial x_2}{\partial y_2}
\end{vmatrix}=
\begin{vmatrix}
1-y_2& -y_1 \\
y_2&y_1
\end{vmatrix}
= (1-y_2)y_1 +y_1y_2=y_1.$$
It follows that the joint density of $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is
$$
f_{Y_1,Y_2}(y_1,y_2)=\begin{cases}
(1-y_2)y_1^2e^{-y_1},& 0<y_1<\infty, 0<y_2<1\\
0,& \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$